# Join 2 tables together and get return all data where it matches (PHP/Laravel5.2 using MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, join, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

I have a variable called $category which a user selects. On submit I need to look inside a table (profiles) for where the $category matches and pull back all of those profiles then look into the likes table and return all matching records for the returned profiles.

My database looks like:

TABLE: profiles

```
ID |   username  | category
-------------------------
 1 |      x      | band  
 2 |      y      | airline
 3 |      z      | airline
```

TABLE: likes

```
ID | account_id  | likes  | created_at
---------------------------------------
 1 |      2      | 1000   | 21/03/2016
 2 |      2      | 2000   | 22/03/2016
 3 |      1      | 3000   | 22/03/2016
```

My code is the following:

```
$category = "band";

$profiles = DB::table('profiles')
            ->join('likes', 'profiles.id', '=', 'likes.account_id')
            ->where('category', '=', $category)
            ->select('profiles.*', 'likes.likes', 'likes.created_at')
            ->get();
```

account_id in the likes table will be the same as id in the profiles table. Also there maybe multiple like records for each profile.
The query just doesn't seem to work and it returns nothing back. I'm using laravel 5.2.

Comment: maybe due to same table and same column name `likes.likes`

Comment: Changed the names of the tables so the table and column no longer are the same. Still get back the same empty array [ ].

Answer (score 0):

```
 $profiles = DB::table('profiles')
        ->leftJoin('likes', 'profiles.id', '=', 'likes.account_id')
        ->where('profiles.category', '=', $category)
        ->select('profiles.*', 'likes.likes', 'likes.created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Tried this, Unfortunately, Still get back. An empty array [ ].